# Does zero correlation imply mean independence in at least one direction?

Tags: independence, correlation

Any example of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ with correlation $\rho(X,Y)=0$ seems to satisfy that either $X$ is mean independent of $Y$, $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]=E[Y]$, or vice versa, $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y] = E[X]$. Does anyone know of a joint distribution in which both $X$ and $Y$ are mean dependent of each other, but their respective correlation is also zero?

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ has standard normal distribution then the covariance of $X$ and $X^2$ is $0$. But they are not mean independent because $E(X^2\mid X) = X^2 \neq EX^2$.

Comment: I have $\mathbb{E}[X|X^2] = 0$.

Comment: @zxc32 Sorry. I switched $X$ and $X^{2}$ in the last line.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a joint distribution such that $\mathbb{E}[Y|X] \neq E[Y]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X|Y] \neq \mathbb{E}[X]$.

Answer (score 1):

I will lazily and shamelessly take this [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Uncorrelatedness_and_independence), which does a fine job summing this up. 
[image]

Comment: Your answer does not seem to address mean independence but only (lack of) independence, which seems to be an important part of the question.

Comment: This does not appear to address what was actually asked.